# Manage publication lists in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, publicationlist

I have a `Test List` publication list in my Marketing Cloud instance, which can is visible to subscribers in their Available Publications on the Subscription Centre page.

I would like to know how I can remove this list? I have tried locating the list under Email Studio > Subscribers > Publication Lists but no items are found.

I have looked at my user permissions and I have all available permissions for Publication Lists set to Allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find this publication list under Subscribers > Publication Lists then you might need to check shared publication list folder because if you delete a publication list from the folder it shouldn't appear on subscription center page or else you might have to open a support ticket to marketing cloud so that their data base engineers can delete desired publication list from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to the Publication list and click on properties and remove the Check on the Public checkbox this will remove it from the subscription page.